# PHP: unset first 3 elements from array

Tags: php, arrays, element, unset

EDIT: I found an alternative to do this: [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice) is a great way.

I have an array called `$mas`. It's fine for me to unset last 7 elements of array, but when I try to unset first 3 elements, I get error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Here is few lines of my code that works:

```
$ilgis = count($mas);
unset($mas[$ilgis-1], $mas[$ilgis-2], $mas[$ilgis-3], $mas[$ilgis-4], $mas[$ilgis-5], $mas[$ilgis-6], $mas[$ilgis-7]);
```

And this code doesn't work:

```
...
unset($mas[0], $mas[1], $mas[2]);
```

It seems like they even don't exist in this array. Any ideas how to fix it?

Btw, `echo $mas[0];` works perfectly.

var_dump($mas) output:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => string 'Paris-Orly - Stockholm-Arlanda' (length=30)
  1 => string 'Tuesday 25. Mar 2014 21:15 - Terminal: S' (length=41)
  2 => string 'Flight DY4314 - LowFare' (length=26)
  3 => string 'Stockholm-Arlanda - Copenhagen' (length=30)
  4 => string 'Wednesday 26. Mar 2014 07:00 - Terminal: 5' (length=43)
  5 => string 'Flight DY4151 - LowFare' (length=26)
  6 => string '1 Adult' (length=7)
  7 => string '1 Child (2-11)' (length=14)
  8 => string '1 Infant' (length=8)
```

Comment: What is output of `var_dump($mas)` ?

Comment: before unset try to `echo $mas[0]`, its exists or not??

Comment: echo $mas[0]; works perfectly

Comment: I edited post with var_dump output

Comment: Show the whole code of the failed case, we need know the context.

Comment: `unset` should not trigger any error for non-existent indexes, it'll just silently do nothing. Please show a complete code sample that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of unsetting values you don't need, you could **select** the values you need. Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) for this purpose. The advantage of this solution over `unset()` is that you don't have to specify the indexes.

```
$mas = array(
    'Paris-Orly - Stockholm-Arlanda',
    'Tuesday 25. Mar 2014 21:15 - Terminal: S',
    'Flight DY4314 - LowFare',
    'Stockholm-Arlanda - Copenhagen',
    'Wednesday 26. Mar 2014 07:00 - Terminal: 5',
    'Flight DY4151 - LowFare',
    '1 Adult',
    '1 Child (2-11)',
    '1 Infant'
);

$output = array_slice($mas, 3); 
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stockholm-Arlanda - Copenhagen
    [1] => Wednesday 26. Mar 2014 07:00 - Terminal: 5
    [2] => Flight DY4151 - LowFare
    [3] => 1 Adult
    [4] => 1 Child (2-11)
    [5] => 1 Infant
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/125683)

Comment: `unset` will not change the index, `unset($mas[0], $mas[1], $mas[2])` should work.

Comment: @xdazz: Where did I get that wrong! Updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use array_shift, wich take the first element and remove it from the array, doesn't matter wich key in case of associative arrays :

```
array_shift($mas) ;
array_shift($mas) ;
array_shift($mas) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

[unset()](http://www.php.net/unset) with the first 3 index works fine for me:

```
$mas = array(
  0 => 'Paris-Orly - Stockholm-Arlanda', 
  1 => 'Tuesday 25. Mar 2014 21:15 - Terminal: S',
  2 => 'Flight DY4314 - LowFare' ,
  3 => 'Stockholm-Arlanda - Copenhagen',
  4 => 'Wednesday 26. Mar 2014 07:00 - Terminal: 5',
  5 => 'Flight DY4151 - LowFare' ,
  6 => '1 Adult' ,
  7 => '1 Child (2-11)' ,
  8 => '1 Infant' );
unset($mas[0], $mas[1], $mas[2]);

var_dump(array_values($mas));
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/125686)**

It however preserves the keys, so might be you are trying to access the index `0` after unsetting. This will throw you the `undefined offset` error and you need to re-index your array. The example above uses [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to do the same.

Comment: Really weird to me it's not working, but I found alternative with array_slice()

Comment: I somehow had the impression that `unset()` peformed a re-indexing of the array, too. Apparently I was wrong! +1 for stating it *does* work. I prefer my `array_slice` solution though :P

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible you first three elements to have keys that are not numeric.

Indices 0,1 and 2 may not even exist.

Check this code out:

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++ ) {
    foreach ( $mas AS $key => $value ) {
        unset( $mas[$key] );
        break;
    }
    reset($mas);
}
```

Comment: You do not need a `foreach` in this case as the loop would execute multiple times than expected. Since the key is numerical, you can skip the inner `foreach` loop and simply do `unset[$i];`